# Translate Express.js ajax handling to PHP

Tags: php, ajax, express

I have a simple jQuery ajax call written in express.js, but due to server hosting requirements, I need to translate it into PHP.

The client-side jQuery:

```
$.get("/get_product_details", function(data){
    alert(data);
});
```

The express.js Node:

```
app.get("/get_product_details", function (req, res) {
    res.json("Success! Your server is talking to the client");
});
```

What would be the simplest and most efficient way to implement this in PHP? 
Thanks.

Comment: With PHP you just perform a query at the time the page loads.

Comment: If you are using a framework you could use the router to define a new route for a get request (GET /get_product_details), otherwise you could create a get_product_details.php page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

express js is framework, in php there are many frameworks with MVC structure which have tools for json response to the client.

In pure PHP you can create your file for example ajax.php and add

```
 <?PHP
$data = /** your data **/;
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($data);
```

and now call /ajax.php from your client

also you can add get parameters

```
 <?PHP
    $data = $_GET['params']
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($data);
```

and now call /ajax.php?params=yourvalue from your client